# Wildfly(JBoss) 9.0.0 changes not reflecting for JSP

Tags: wildfly-8

I am using Wildfly(JBoss) 9.0.0 on Eclipse LUNA, if I make changes on the JSP the same is not getting reflected on the browser. I have to restart the server every time. However this was not the case with Jboss 7.2 where the changes were shown directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set jsp-config to enable development mode in your Wildfly standalone.xml.

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config development="true" keep-generated="false" check-interval="1" modification-test-interval="1"/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```